# How to set limit_req on a certain folders?

Tags: nginx

How can I set limit_req on all folders except on a "uploads and public" for example.

What I've tried:

```
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/public;
                            if ( $uri !~ ^/(uploads|public) ) {
                                limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
                            }
...
```

error:

```
nginx: [emerg] "limit_req" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my.conf:20
```

Answer (score 0):

[`limit_req`](http://nginx.org/r/limit_req) is not allowed inside `if` as you have it here. It's only allowed in `http`, `server` or `location`.

So you will need to have `location` blocks for each of these.

```
location /public/ {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
}
location /uploads/ {
    limit_req zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
}
```